# Lodash _.merge function issue

Tags: javascript, lodash

```
_ = require('lodash');

var a = [
  {
    'name': 'MyGroup',
    'description': null,
    'items': [
      {
        '_id': 'uStqrALmwWCdyzBnc',
        'type': 'endpoints'
      },
      {
        '_id': 'tpCSiT65R5PHmQ2yn',
        'type': 'endpoints'
      }
    ],
    '_id': '8phfSHKLt9c5SB2YM'
  }
];

var b = [
  {
    'name': 'MyGroup',
    'description': null,
    'items': [
      {
        '_id': 'GET_test',
        'type': 'endpoints'
      }
    ]
  }
];

console.log(JSON.stringify(_.merge(a, b), null, 2));
```

Giving this output:

```
    [
  {
    "name": "MyGroup",
    "description": null,
    "items": [
      {
        "_id": "GET_test",
        "type": "endpoints"
      },
      {
        "_id": "tpCSiT65R5PHmQ2yn",
        "type": "endpoints"
      }
    ],
    "_id": "8phfSHKLt9c5SB2YM"
  }
]
```

reversing a and b results in only b object, I could understand a couldn't get merged somehow. But why this is getting merged partially and not completely? Is it logical or a bug?

Answer (score 5):

It's logical. Merge doesn't know anything about your intentions for the array: it just patches in the item you have from the second object into the right spot, overwriting, not appending or concating or something else.

What you probably want here is _.mergeWith, which allows you to specify a custom function to handle special cases as you desire.  In fact, the docs actually describe exactly the situation you're probably in (wanting some particular operation, say, concat, to happen when two arrays are being merged) https://lodash.com/docs#mergeWith

Answer (score 5):

I think lodash is behaving as designed. It tries to recursively merge your objects, and that means, to lodash, that the objects in your `items` array ought to be merged together. So, the result is not as we expect, but maybe logical to lodash.

You might have better luck with [`_.mergeWith`](https://lodash.com/docs#mergeWith), providing a customizer that handles arrays with `_.union`:

```
_.mergeWith(a, b, function(objValue, srcValue) { if (_.isArray(objValue)) { return _.union(objValue, srcValue); }})
```

or, more easy to read:

```
function customizer(objValue, srcValue) {
    if (_.isArray(objValue)) {
        return _.union(objValue, srcValue);
    }
}

_.mergeWith(a, b, customizer);
```

the customizer function can be made smarter, if need be.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure what Rana expects: since a and b are both arrays with a single item, are they supposed to overwrite each other?  Or concat?  And if they're supposed to overwrite in the top-level case of merging arrays, why wouldn't they do the same thing in other, internal case?  But if instead Rana intends to just concat a and b, then there is no merging of anything below anyhow...

Comment: missing closing parenthesis on isarray